# Having issues executing multiple javascript lines in chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

I have been trying to do some manipulation on webpages using JavaScript. So I started with the basic Google page(https://google.com).
I ran the command
**document.getElementById('lst-ib').value = 'search_term';**

Then after that tried running
**document.getElementsByName('btnI')[0].click();**
which is the *I'm feeling Lucky* button.

It is showing *undefined* on doing so.

But when I try only click on the *I'm Feeling Lucky* button without changing the content of the search bar, it works.

The target is to click the *Search Button*, it is also not working.
So I used the *I'm Feeling Lucky* button for testing to see if anything can be clicked.

**The Same is happening in YouTube search bar as well**

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.
Also please note that I am N00b and trying to learn as I go :(

TLDR; **The Idea is to simulate all the operation a user can do on the browsers using JavaScript.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('lst-ib').value = 'search_term';
document.getElementById('tsf').submit();
```

(or `document.querySelector("form").submit();`)

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, but did you consider just using the queryparams? google.com?search=search_term ?

I found this ID simply by going to google.com, rightclicking on the input field, choose 'inspect element' and search for the first ancestor that is a 'form'.

[image]

Comment: This worked! I am actually trying to simulate all the things a user can do on a page using javascript. I am a beginner to all of this and completely new, so I am learning as I go. If there is anything like what I am looking for, please guide me there. Also, if you could, please tell me how you found the ID to be **tsf**, I have tried and finally had to use the name :( . Sorry to sound like such a noob.

Comment: Don't have to talk down on yourself :) Everybody learns one step at a time.